# Downsides of using requestAnimationFrame when not needed

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I'm currently rebuilding a site to run on mobile and therefore I have to - for performance reasons - take out almost all animations (the desktop site makes heavy use of jQuery animations). The animationloop uses **requestAnimationFrame()** for smooth transistions.
I'm wondering if there is any downside to leaving it in even though it's not really needed.

It's mostly a question out of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be, unless it's actually doing any work. As long as it isn't, it won't affect things at all.

Comment: Just dug into that question again and found the following issue with Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=120186 It does affect the page under Chrome by creating unnecessary garbage.